# Django Admin encrypt values of certain fields on changed(or save) with save_model()

Tags: python, django, encryption, django-admin

I currently having a custom User model which some of the fields are supposed to be encrypted (data side) but on Django Admin they need to be decrypted to show the actual data so i have `encrypt_string()` and `decrypt_string()` function to handle it.

My user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    uid = models.CharField(
      "uid", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(
        "Nickname", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    
    eth_address = models.CharField(
        "Eth address", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    eth_private_key = models.CharField(
        "Eth private key", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    evt_address = models.CharField(
        "Evt address", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    evt_private_key = models.CharField(
        "Evt private key", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

eth_address, eth_private_key, evt_address and evt_private_key need to be encrypted when doing any kind of saving or edit

Currently when my server request from an api it will create a default user(handle on custom authentication_class of django-rest-framework):

existed_user_check = User.objects.filter(uid=uid).exists()

```
    if not existed_user_check:
        random_password = ''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, 6)])
        eth_address, eth_private_key = generate_eth()
        evt_address, evt_private_key = generate_evt()
        new_user = User(
            username=uid, 
            uid=uid, 
            eth_address=encrypt_string(eth_address), 
            eth_private_key=encrypt_string(eth_private_key), 
            evt_address=encrypt_string(evt_address), 
            evt_private_key=encrypt_string(evt_private_key)
        )
        new_user.set_password(random_password)
        new_user.save()
```

And on my Django Admin i wrote the following in the admin.py to handle decrypt(when showing the data on change view) and encrypt(when doing any saving or edit of those 4 fields):

```
user_profile_encrypt_fields = [
    'eth_address',
    'eth_private_key',
    'evt_address',
    'evt_private_key'
]
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in user_profile_encrypt_fields:
            if getattr(self.instance, field) is not None:
                try:
                    self.initial[field] = decrypt_string(getattr(self.instance, field))
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
        

class UserAdminCustom(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # UserAdminForm handle decrypt data
    form = UserAdminForm
    exclude = ('password', 'last_login', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'groups',
               'user_permissions', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'date_joined')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdminCustom, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(is_staff=False)

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return ('id', 'created', 'modified')
    
    # save_model() handle encrypt data on saving
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        for field in form.changed_data:
            if form.cleaned_data.get(field) is not None:
                if field in user_profile_encrypt_fields:
                    encrypted_value = encrypt_string(form.cleaned_data.get(field))
                    setattr(obj, field, encrypted_value)
        obj.save()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdminCustom)
```

Custom UserAdminForm for me to decrypt the data so the admin can see what it's when they doing the editing or checking.
The decrypted data are able to be showed on the change view correctly

save_model() will handle the encrypting of data when admin edit a fields on Django Admin change view.

**My current problem:**

**NOTES:**

The data in these fields existed so i'm only talking about the editing object part on django admin.

When ever i tried to edit any of the field and save it(should be encrypted) that field got encrypted and saved, but the field below it (actual encrypted data of it) now changed to it's actual data(not encrypted)

**After i edited evt_address on the change view and save**

decrypted data when use `form = UserAdminForm`

[image]

comment out `# form = UserAdminForm` on the UserAdminCustom so it show the actual data

[image]

I printed out the `getattr(self.instance, field)` to see the encrypted data on loading the django admin change view and got the following 4 encrypted field:

```
web_1         | eth_address : gAAAAABeAcoI08bH2fQqJboZFxg6xn5RCxdRopllS6fDeyRmsC3qzsTXo88NVYOb58eeX5IXQpxqcGhbLr8wRRoWSKQsX5vLbPPhmWqUiqf0XYQvdWUhhgYxxMwwqgEOwU2OtJfkZ0p6
web_1         | eth_private_key : gAAAAABeAcoIp1V9sKNnL-dO-fWH1W1oM7hbqky44aRLchmTtvckaaZdaKuXo1xIIozx3xl40Y2Ct3YAyCOfkJJranKgTNDcVhndYdu5-awOuYpPCJKkSSia7IP_gWjLE91Gh8vsGnkn1iEkrLaho2ff0vVHS1QgGaJxji5m7cwCk0tqSp2AIeA=
web_1         | evt_address : gAAAAABeAcoIM3rywSgAPL611WUoWLJ9mqIgUHhZn8KDQd9hi9xHzgRri0EkoS_yBvwQyzdH72RWJRsDCs38oF9P8HHW_wFDWQ==
web_1         | evt_private_key : 1814067
```

so my `evt_private_key` data got changed to `1814067` after i edited `evt_address` value and save

Why is this happening, i'm so confused on what causing this.

Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple attempts to modify `save_model` function i realized the data of the form actually came from `UserAdminForm` so to be able to modify the data on django admin form i need to encrypt it from the form itself before saving

```
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in user_profile_encrypt_fields:
            if getattr(self.instance, field) is not None:
                try:
                    self.initial[field] = decrypt_string(getattr(self.instance, field))
                except:
                    pass

    def clean_eth_address(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['eth_address'] is not None:
            data = encrypt_string(self.cleaned_data['eth_address'])
        else:
            data = None

        return data

    def clean_eth_private_key(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['eth_private_key'] is not None:
            data = encrypt_string(self.cleaned_data['eth_private_key'])
        else:
            data = None

        return data

    def clean_evt_address(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['evt_address'] is not None:
            data = encrypt_string(self.cleaned_data['evt_address'])
        else:
            data = None

        return data

    def clean_evt_private_key(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['evt_private_key'] is not None:
            data = encrypt_string(self.cleaned_data['evt_private_key'])
        else:
            data = None

        return data
```

And now whenever i make a change on the admin form it will get encrypted

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it on incorrect layer of abstraction.

Please follow this guide in order to create a custom Django field that will handle encryption / decryption for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/

Or just use some existing solution, like: https://github.com/foundertherapy/django-cryptographic-fields

Comment: using custom model field is a good idea but that not what i'm going for, since in the future i might use decrypt values too. And i also want to change value if a field got save or changed on django admin, this is a function that i will use alot in the future

Comment: @LinhNguyen that's the idea. The custom field will work with django admin without any changes needed.

Comment: i would go for that in the next project i do , i just want a solution for the changing values of django admin (maybe not encrypt/decrypt way but format certain fields on save) cause i'm planning to use it in the future

Comment: I have had success with this: https://django-fernet-fields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: django-cryptographic-fields hasnt't been updated since 2016. Also, it uses keyczar, which is depricated.